# How to update Azure Application Gateway using Azure.ResourceManager library in dotnet?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm currently working on a .NET project and I need to update an Azure Application Gateway using the Azure.ResourceManager library. I've previously attempted to use the `UpdateAsync()` methode available on the `ApplicationGatewayResource` object but it allow only to update tags, not the full gateway config.

```
ApplicationGatewayResource appGateway = await _armClient.GetApplicationGatewayResource(ResourceIdentifier.Parse(_configuration["Azure:ApplicationGatewayId"])).GetAsync();
                        
appGateway.Data.SslCertificates.Add(new ApplicationGatewaySslCertificate
{
    Name = name,
    Data = new BinaryData(pfx),
    Password = pfxPassword
});
await appGateway.UpdateAsync(new());
```

Can someone provide an updated example of how to update an Azure Application Gateway using the current version of Azure.ResourceManager library in .NET ? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I finally found a solution:

```
ApplicationGatewayResource appGateway = await _armClient.GetApplicationGatewayResource(ResourceIdentifier.Parse(_configuration["Azure:ApplicationGatewayId"])).GetAsync();
                    
// Update gateway object 

var resourceGroup = _armClient.GetResourceGroupResource(Parse(_configuration["Azure:ResourceGroupId"]!));
var gatewayCollection = resourceGroup.GetApplicationGateways();
await gatewayCollection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, appGateway.Data.Name, appGateway.Data);
```